# Renaming only substring in variables in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a list of variables in Stata like `a_1_va_0100` , `a_2_va_0100` , `a_3_va_0100`, etc. The maximum number is not fixed (would not be more than 50) . The number in the variables will be sequential but maximum number can vary in different cases.

I need to replace the variables to `a_1_q0100`, `a_2_q0200`, `a_3_q0300`, etc. The first 4 characters will remain as they are and the remaining will change . I have tried using `subinstr()`.

```
 replace a_1_va_0100 = subinstr( a_1_va_0100 , "va_0100", "q0100", .)
```

Can I loop the replace statement for each variable?

Comment: You have to be clear on the difference between the names of variables and their values. No programming is possible otherwise.

Comment: Note that you still have pending feedback on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368972/front-end-in-stata. It's at least corteous to give noticeable feedback on questions you pose.

Comment: This is just a flag that the OP promised to fix this question. Until that is done, the question is just no conceivable use to anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `rename`, not `replace` (my guess):

```
clear
set obs 1

gen a_1_va_0100 = 1
gen a_2_va_0100 = 2
gen a_3_va_0100 = 3

describe

forvalues i = 100(100)300 {
    rename a_`=`i'/100'_va_0100 a_`=`i'/100'_q0`i'
}

describe
```

Alternatively:

```
forvalues i = 1/3 {
    rename a_`i'_va_0100 a_`i'_q0`=`i'*100'
}
```

We use `replace` to change values taken by a particular variable, not to `rename` variables. See `help <command>` for details.

Or do you really want to `replace` values?

Comment: I meant replace and not rename . I will change the original post . The alternate solution worked for me . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all occurrences of "va_" by "q" in your variable names for variables starting with "a_":

`renvars a_*, subst(va_ q)`

You can install this Stata Journal command after locating it with `findit renvars`.

Comment: Note that you would need to download `renvars` from the _Stata Journal_ site first.